# The type arguments for method … cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I'm not sure, why calling `Map2` gives me

> The type arguments for method 'Program.Map2(object,
>   Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the
>   type arguments explicitly.

Here is the code...

```
void Test()
{
    var test1 = Map1(1, MapIntToString);
    var test2 = Map2(1, MapIntToString);
}

To Map1<From, To>(From value, Func<From, To> mapFunc) => mapFunc(value);
To Map2<From, To>(object value, Func<From, To> mapFunc) => mapFunc((From)value);

string MapIntToString(int value) => Convert.ToString(value);
```

This is very simplified example. I need to convert some lists of DTOs to Models (and back), but it should be same case...

Comment: In `Map1`, you easily let it infer the `From` is `int` since that's the type of the first parameter. In `Map2`, it doesn't know where to start with `From`

Comment: Also, bear in mind that at the *call site* for `Map1` and `Map2`, the compiler has no information about how those methods are implemented - it can only work from the method signatures - and even if it could do deeper inspection, the cast is in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have defined the parameter of type `object` while the method `MapIntToString` has first parameter of type `int`. So the compiler is not able to figure out that the parameter passed to `mapFunc` for `Map2` i.e `object value` is currently holding value of type `int`. Your code will be translated to something like below if we visualize it when will be resolved at run-time but at first place it is not compiling as it's not able to resolve the generic type `From`:

```
Map2<Object, String>(object value, Func<object, String> mapFunc) => mapFunc((object)value);
```

So, obviously this wouldn't work as your method expects parameter of type `int` not `object`.

You need to be explicit about the type parameters in this case as Compiler is not smart enough to know that the `object value` is currently holding value of type `int` in it.

Comment: Why would the compiler assume that `From` is `object` but magically know that `To` is `string`? The first parameter is not generic and therefor has nothing to do with inferring the type parameters. Best case you end up with the question why the compiler can infer the type of `Func<int,?>` but not `Func<?,?>` from a method group.

Answer (score 0):

Being explicit works:

```
var test2 = Map2<int, string>(1, MapIntToString);
```

or

```
var test2 = Map2(1, (Func<int, string>)MapIntToString);
```

I'm afraid I cannot point to the reason *why* it does not work implicitly. My personal guess would be that `MapIntToString` is *not* a single method, but a Method Group (with one member) that can be converted to a `Func<int, string>` without problems, but that conversion is not used in resolving generics.